# How to set a referenced variable to null?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reference

here is my use case :

on Phaser.io, when a user hit a button, I set a Phaser.sprite to a local `let newSquare` variable, and I `.push()` it to the `Squares` array of Phaser.sprite.

Later, I call some `destroy` function on that `newSquare`variable, and then I set it to null. While the sprite is well removed from the screen after the `.destroy()`, I can still access it from my `Squares` array...

I thought that, being an object if I set the `newSquare`variable to null, it'd be set to null for all the other references too, shouldn't it ?

So why is my ref in the `Squares` array not set to null ?

Excerpt :

```
eventFunction ( e, i ) {
      let newSquare = Game.add.sprite( Lines.attack.a, 0, 'square');

      // Some other methods call here
      Squares[ e.target.dataset.line ].push( newSquare );

      setTimeout( () => {
        if ( newSquare ) {
          newSquare.destroy();
          newSquare = null;
          console.log(Squares); // will print an array with an iteration corresponding to newSquare object, when I want it to be set to null, in order to clean the array with a _.pull()
        }
      }, ( 2 * 1000 ) );

}
```

What am I missing here ? Thanks you.

Comment: not really. you can have multiple references to the same "thing". setting one of those references to null doesn't invalidate the other references. But calling `.destroy()` WILL invalidate them . you explicitly destroyed the object, which means anything else using those other references will now be trying to use their "pointer" to an object which was destroyed. It'd be like having 3 notes around your house saying "socks in drawer under bed". If you burn one of the postits, you'll still have socks in the drawer. but if you burn the drawer, those notes will STILL say there's socks there.

Comment: @MarcB I don't know what exactly `.destroy` does in Phaser but I imagine a better analogy would be that it closes and locks the sock drawer. So it is still there, all the signs still point to it, and it probably still has socks but you can't get to them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're only nullifying the reference to the object that was originally created. The object still exists in memory and has a reference to it through array access. This means that it won't get garbage collected. You will need to nullify it within the array...

Here is a simplified version of your problem.

```
let x = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3};
let y = x;

x = null;
console.log(y);
// => {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
```

I'd say keep the reference to the item in memory and use that reference to find the index of the object within the array that you `push`ed to. E.g.,

```
array.find(el => el === reference)
```

...where `reference` is the identifier that you were previously assigning to `null`.

A way to nullify the element and maintain its current position within the array is to map over your collection using the `reference` to locate your item. E.g.,

```
array = array.map(el => el === reference ? null : el)
```

If you're looking for a mutative way to modify the element in-place, use a `forEach(..)`. E.g.,

```
array.forEach((x, i, arr) => {
  if (x === reference) {
    arr[i] = null;
  }
  return;
});
```

The `forEach` call will visit each element in your array, so if you'd like to short-circuit the iteration, try using `indexOf` loop.

```
const i = array.indexOf(reference);
array[i] = null;
```

Comment: `array.map(...)` that will not modify the array in-place.

Comment: Yea you're right. I guess I used "in-place" too liberally. I meant at its current position in the array. I'll change it to a mutative `forEach(..)`

Comment: So, my `newSquare` variable refer to a memory zone where my object starts, okay. But how can I unset what is at this memory adress through `newSquare` ?? If I can access the object and call its method, I should well be able to have a wayto say "put a bunch of 0 bits where my newSquare points", no ?

Comment: @DavidPanart not directly, not in JavaScript. It doesn't really allow you that amount of control over the object. You _could_ just use `delete` to remove all properties, which would, in turn, make it a smaller object and presumably GC will collect all the properties, but if you only have the object in a variable, e.g., `var myObj = obj` you can't just make it disappear. You have to remove all references to it, which means, either not keeping any (permanently, that is) or doing manual cleanup of any global variables that would hold it.

Comment: forEach can be a good way to do with my use case, as I only work with arrays of 3/4 iterations, at a framerate of 45 fps, but it might get very costly if those numbers went to grow, so isn't there a way to unset the object through the `newSquare` ref ?

Comment: Tested with the forEach, but as I suspected while coding it, it does not change the value of my array's item. It does well change the tmp `el` variable, but not the ref in the array itself, as the tmp `el`is itself another ref.

It should work though whith  a `while` (which is better at performances than a forEach anyway)

Comment: @DavidPanart you are correct - that `forEach` is wrong, it does not change the array. I proposed an edit, but until it gets (hopefully) accepted the correct code is `array.forEach((el, key, array) => {if (el === reference) { array[key] = null; }});` - this will actually set the place in the array to `null`. You can also use `.splice()` to completely remove the item from the array `array.splice(key, 1)`

Comment: @DavidPanart made some edits to the answer. Apologies for any confusion. Hopefully the answer is clearer now